# Trying to install plugin with plugman to phonegap hybrid ios app / cordova-universal-links-plugin / cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

Initially, I am trying to install `Facebook Auth` but I am running into the error:

```
Error: cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix is not installed
```

I think I need to install `cordova-universal-links-plugin` using `plugman`, and I am trying like this:

```
plugman --platform ios --project /Volumes/EamonWD/hybridpool/HybridPool --plugin https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin --plugins_dir /Volumes/EamonWD/hybridpool/HybridPool/Pods/phonegap-ios-template/resources/www/plugins --www /Volumes/EamonWD/hybridpool/HybridPool/Pods/phonegap-ios-template/resources/www
```

`/Volumes/EamonWD/hybridpool/HybridPool` - location of `HybridPool.xcworkspace` and `HybridPool.xcproj`

I created the XCode project for `HybridPool` `hybrid` app following the `cocoapods` instructions here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/1-embed-webview/ios/

I think all of the parameters are the correct locations, but when I hit enter, it just spits back the `plugman` manual (because something is wrong). What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

In the manual it says:

> plugman manages plugin.xml-compatible cordova plugins into
>   cordova-generated projects.

But I don't have a plugin.xml file I don't think...

**UPDATE**

I noticed in the repo:

https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin/blob/master/plugin.xml

So the plugin has a `plugin.xml` file, so maybe `plugin.xml` isn't the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot `install` in command, should be `plugman install ...`